# How to create dll in c++ with undecorate export functions

Tags: c++, dll, name-decoration

Whenever I create dll in c++ the exported functions get decorated. How can I get undecorated functions.

```
class Trying{
private:
    void xyz();
public:
    static __declspec(dllexport) int WriteUserData(int data);
    static __declspec(dllexport) string SomeFunction(string data);
}
```

I am exporting only the two public functions `WriteUserData` and `SomeFunction`. But on exporting I get decorated names like `?WriteUserData@@@@SB@@l`
Most posts mention about using `extern "C"` as  `extern "C"static __declspec(dllexport) int WriteUserData(int data);`but they are using it in functions that are outside any function. I cannot place `extern "C"` before the functions inside the class as it gives error `linkage specification is not allowed`.

Comment: It is not terribly obvious why these functions need to be members of a class.  But as-is, you need a .def file to rename the exports.

Comment: There are many more private functions the the two exported functions use internally. So they are shown in a class